# How can I pass table output to another view controller?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I realize that similar questions have been asked, but have spent hours trying to solve a problem. I'm a newbie. I bet it's just an import statement or variable declaration.

I used a tabbed FirstViewController to call SecondVieWController which has a TableView on it. The output of the table is caught in a label, tableOutput beneath the table on SecondViewController. [It works.] I press the tab and return to FirstViewController. How do I access that tableOutput value, to put it, for example, into a label called titleLabel?

I tried variations of
               titleLable.text=SecondViewController.tableOutput.text

but just get error messages that "Property tableOutput not found on object of type UIViewController".

I was able to do it using a popover controller in an iPad app, but am having trouble implementing this similar thing starting with an iPhone tabbed view controller.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

-Rob

Comment: Can you please be more explicit? Maybe add an image or a piece of code? I don't actually understand the question

Comment: Please try to be careful with terminology so that we can better understand you. Xcode isn't doing anything here, it's just the IDE, so I've removed references to it from the tags and title. Also, we don't normally think of a table as having "output;" I think you're just talking about some data from the selected row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is get a reference to your actual `SecondViewController` object.  The easiest way I can think of to do this is create an IBOutlet hookup to your `SecondViewController` object, then access the label through that member.

In your FirstViewController.h:

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface 

    @property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet SecondViewController *secondView;

@end
```

In  FirstViewController.m:

```
@implementation FirstViewController

@synthesize secondView;
```

Once you have that declared, go into your xib file, and make the link between the FirstViewController and the SecondViewController

Then you can access the `tableOutput` label as

```
secondView.tableOutput.text;
```

EDIT:

Looking at the way new tabbed applications are set up initially, your view controllers are probably created in code in the AppDelegate.m file like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Using the same idea as I outlined above, only you don't need to declare the linkage as an IBOutlet:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) SecondViewController* secondView;
```

Then as the viewcontrollers are created, you can change it to look like this

```
FirstViewController *viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
SecondViewController *viewController2 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
viewController1.secondView = viewController2;
```

And then access the label as I showed originally

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, Dan. How do I link Controllers? When I select SecondViewController.xib, I only see that controller on the page. (I'm not using storyboards). How do I link it to FirstViewController?

Comment: Well if you are using a `UITabViewController`, then in your main xib file, both of those view controllers are contained within the tabviewcontroller in that xib.  Unless of course you are creating the view controllers in code

Comment: I did it in code (I guess!). I started with a Tabbed Application which gave me two view controllers and a tabbar at the bottom. I put a table view onto SecondViewController. I got the table loading from an array and putting the title of the row selected into tableOutput (label), but haven't been able to pass the selected row (tableOutput.text) back to FirstViewController. -Rob

Comment: BTW, I tried the line titleLabel.text = secondView.tableOutput.text into FirstViewController's viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, and viewDidLoad

Comment: I took a look at how tabbed applications are set up in the new version of xcode, and updated my answer above

Answer (score 0):

For others with similar needs:

With thanks to Dan F, I still couldn't quite get the my app to pass the table output in one VC to another VC. In this YouTube video, Connor Denman provided a solution: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5cW90_aYqg

1. Get table output in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

tableOutput.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tableArray objectAt Index: indexPath.row]];

1. As demonstrated on the video, define class and string variable in the AppDelegate. (e.g. appDelegate and myString)
2. Assign the value of tableOutput to the variable:

appDelegate.myString=tableOutput.text

1. In the other view controller's viewWillAppear routine, use

   titleLabel.text = appDelegate.myString

The video shows what imports, declarations, @property, and @synthesis statements you need.

-Thanks to Connor, and Dan, above, for their help.

-Rob